# is there a shortcut to get window.history.back()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

AFAIK, the only way to get Angular mimick a back button behavior is via a call to `$window.history.back`.

Now, I have a form with two buttons: submit and cancel. When I submit, I have some custom logic, and in the end I can easily call the back() method. But how could I achieve the same without a custom method for the cancel button?

This is my current html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save(berlet)">Ok</button>
    <a class="btn btn-warning" ui-sref="jogasok">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

I would like to have a `back()` behavior when clicking the `<a>` tag. Are there any recommendations for it? My preferred syntax would be something like: `Cancel :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a simple directive, to keep your controller free from redundant $window pollution:

<kbd>**[PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/ucFyvNsBNinhUdpyamya?p=preview)**</kbd>

```js
app.directive('goBack', function($window){
  return function($scope, $element){
    $element.on('click', function(){
      $window.history.back();
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<a go-back>Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

My best idea until now is to attach the `$window` service to my directive, and call the back button through the `$scope`.

```
<a class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="window.history.back()">Cancel</a>
```

and in my directive I have

```
$scope.window = $window;
```